# Transform root association data Active Model Serializers 0.9.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-model-serializers

Im basically trying to return some data using active model serializers using a key - value pair objects instead of an array for my association. So, instead of

```
{ 
  books: [{
   id: 1,
   title: "Foo"
  }],
  comments: [...]
}
```

I want

```
{ 
  books: [{
   id: 1,
   title: "Foo"
  }],
  comments: {
    "1": { 
      id: 1,
      content: "Bar"
    }
  }
}
```

So far what im doing is this but i get:
NoMethodError (undefined method `id' for # Hash:0x00007f8d1b24d100 ):

```
class BookSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :title, :description, :created_by, :created_at

  has_many :comments

  def comments
    object.comments.index_by(&:id)
  end
end
```

I am using AMS 0.9.7 and rails 5.0

Comment: What does return `object.comments`? I suppose, you don't have there `ActiveRecord::Relation` or `Array`, you have some `Hash` instead there. So there is a reasonable question - how do you call this serializer?

Comment: class CommentSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer 
  attributes :id, :content
end

Comment: What about `index_by { |comment| comment["id"] }` ? Can you show the result of `object.comments.first.keys` ?

Comment: I get NoMethodError: undefined method `keys' for #<Comment:0x00007f8d1b46bb80>

Comment: Still object.comments.first shows `#<Comment:0x00007f8d1b46bb80
 id: 2,
 content: "Listen to Don Giovanni",
 book_id: 2,
 created_at: Sun, 28 Jan 2018 23:09:08 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Sun, 28 Jan 2018 23:09:08 UTC +00:00>

Comment: and `object.comments.first.superclass` is?  Is that an `ActiveRecord::Model`?

Comment: `object.comments.first.superclass` show undefined method `superclass' for #<Comment:0x00007f8d1b1b9a18> but  `object.comments.first.class` shows `Comment(id: integer, content: text, book_id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)` which indeed is kinda weird

Comment: `object.comments.index_by { |c| c[:id] }` - is your solution.

Comment: Still getting `NoMethodError (undefined method id for #<Hash:0x00007f8d19baca18>)`

Comment: Maybe has many associations are only suppose to return arrays

Comment: Not quiet sure if this is something possible to do

Answer (score 0):

Change the `BookSerializer#comments` method in the following way:

`def comments
    object.comments.index_by { |c| c[:id] }
  end`

Comment: Still getting `NoMethodError (undefined method id for #<Hash:0x00007f8d19baca18>)`